# Hide Filter Button on only a couple of columns in a formatted Table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a formatted table that works as intended. However, for visual reasons I would like to hide the filter buttons on the column headers that don´t need it
The Headers I have are:

| Project Name| Project Owner | ID | Supplier | Sales January | Sales Feb | Sales March | SUM of Q1|..etc

I really only need the filter option on the first three columns (Project Owner ; Id; Supplier)
Is it possible to hide the filter arrow button on the rest of the columns?

The reason why I need it to be a formatted table ( rather than formatted as Range and with individual filters on specific columns ) is because the formulas in the rest of the column( like the sum of the sales) are automatically copied everytime someone adds a new row. A behaviour I have not been able to replicate without a formatted table. When I try to do it using the information without any formatting , some formulas are copied when a new row is inserted ( for example first column project name copies the formula correctly) but not the others (for example sum of Q1) and the cell is left empty.  I also tried to do this with a VBA code, but the behaviour always launched when people were doing a double clik rather than actually inserting a new row( sometimes peple may want to double click and not necessarily create a new row).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have already try to disable  the Filter Button on Table Style Options, but this dissables ALL of the filter buttons, not only on selected columns

I have also tried creating a Table without headers and just hide the headers and try to filter on only the columns I want to , but that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added `VBA` as a tag, but the only way I know to do this is with VBA:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1") 'Update to your table name.
    
    Dim lc As ListColumn
    For Each lc In lo.ListColumns
        If lc.Index > 3 Then
            lc.Range.Cells(1).AutoFilter Field:=lc.Index, VisibleDropDown:=False
        End If
    Next lc

End Sub
```